# How to add click event or mouseover action on input type="image" or <img> tag?

Tags: angular, typescript

This code is used for image strip on HTML but I need to add click or mouseover action on this images.

```
<div class="thumbnailImageStrip">
            <ul class="models">
                <li *ngFor="let model of models" (click)="onImageClick(model.imageUrl)">
                    <input type="image" [src]="model.imageUrl" />
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!--<div class="overlay">
                <div class="text">Hello World</div>
            </div>-->
        </div>
```

Comment: you already have an on-click example handler on the li element..

Comment: I use on click but it hitting when page is load

Comment: you should try to describe what you want better. what should happen when.

Comment: I want click on image after load page and preview that image on other <img> tag

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean for this line:

```
<input type="image" [src]="model.imageUrl" />
```

To be this:

```
<img [src]="model.imageUrl" />
```

Then you could do:

```
<img [src]="model.imageUrl" (click)="doClickStuff($event)/>
```

Comment: dear chrispy, I add like above you tell but this function hitting when page load, but i want this action after page load